# Downgrade PHP to 5.3 on Fedora 17

Tags: linux, php, fedora

I'm trying to downgrade PHP to 5.3 on Fedora 17. Using `yum downgrade` I can only get as low as 5.4.1 (instead of 5.4.3).

How can I install 5.3 using yum?

I'm following the details at http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=234132 but I get the following error:

```
Skip-broken could not solve problems 
Error: Package: php-cli-5.3.13-1.fc16.x86_64 (updates-16)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) 
Error: Package: php-5.3.13-1.fc16.x86_64 (updates-16)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)  
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that won't work.. your best bet is to completely remove php from your system. Find the version you want to use and install the src rpm and use the spec file from that to build a php package for your system.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just installing from source instead.